# Who had the best time cards?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Ok. Me and my friends were playing poker when we were stuck on a hand. On the board was a KKQ3J player 1 had a 3,4 meanwhile player 2 had a A,5 and although player 1 did have a pair of 3's we were confused cause we were thinking player 2 won because they had the A and that would have made it the best 5 cards so could you please explain to me who really won the hand.

Comment: Hing - 2 pair beats 1 pair

Comment: Until you are intimately familiar with hands, it may help to use a ranking chart such as this: http://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker/hand-rankings

Answer (score 1):

The best 5 Cards in this hand are KK33Q (Assuming no flushes).  The losing hand was KKAQJ.